# I have to tap my log in button twice to log in my android application

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio

```
public class LoginInterface extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button bLogin;
    EditText etUsername, etPassword;
    TextView tvRegisterLink;
    String username;
    boolean ifReturn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_interface);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blogin);
        bLogin.setTransformationMethod(null);
        tvRegisterLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterLink);
        bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvRegisterLink.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void saveInfo(View view){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("user_info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("email", etUsername.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("password", etPassword.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();
    }
    public void getInfo(View view){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("user_info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String email = sharedPref.getString("email", "");
        String password = sharedPref.getString("password", "");
        if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()){
//            Intent i = new Intent(this, Profile.class);
//            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//            bundle.putString("username", username);
//            i.putExtras(bundle);
//            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    public void alert(String message){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).create().show();
    }
    // a method that takes the text that user entered and compare them with the correct user account and password stored on userinfo.txt file.

    public void volley() {
        final ProgressDialog proDia = new ProgressDialog(this);
        proDia.setTitle("Processing");
        proDia.setMessage("Please wait...");
        proDia.show();
        // Instantiate the cache
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap
// Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
// Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
        RequestQueue mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
// Start the queue
        mRequestQueue.start();
// Add request to queue
        String url = "http://percyteng.com/get_users_details.php";
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            username = new JSONObject(response).getString("user");
                            proDia.dismiss();
                            ifReturn = true;
//                            JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("user");
//                            for (int i = 0; i< jsonResponse.length(); i++){
//                                JSONObject eachuser = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
//                                String useremail = eachuser.getString("useremail");
//                                String password = eachuser.getString("password");
//                                alert(useremail + "," + password);
//                            }
//                            username = jsonResponse.getString("username");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            alert("Incorrect user information.");
                            proDia.dismiss();
                            ifReturn = false;
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
                // the POST parameters:
                params.put("useremail", etUsername.getText().toString());
                params.put("password", etPassword.getText().toString());
                return params;
            }
        };

            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);
        if (ifReturn) {
            alert("bitch");
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Profile.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("username", username);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.tvRegisterLink:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Register.class));
                break;
            case R.id.blogin:
                String ed_Name = etUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                String ed_Password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                if (ed_Name.isEmpty()){
                    alert("Wrong input,please enter your user name.");
                }
                else if (ed_Password.isEmpty()){
                    alert("Wrong input, please enter your password.");
                }
                else{
                    volley();
//                    etPassword.setText("");
//                    etUsername.setText("");
                }
                break;

        }
    }

}
```

This is the code in my android studio, which works perfectly fine. My problem is in my login interface, the first time I tap the log in button, it would not do anything, but I am pretty sure that the server already received the log in message cuz the second time I tap the login button, it starts activity in response to my first button tap. When I try to login with another account, it logs in with the previous account for the first attemp. In other words, my log in activities got shift after one attempt. It's quite hard to explain. so my second tap responds to the first startActivity() basicalliy.

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will get single product details
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

$response = array();
if (isset($_POST['useremail']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $useremail = $_POST['useremail'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
    try{
        // connecting to db
        $con = new DB_CONNECT();
        $db = $con->connect();
        // mysql inserting a new row
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT username FROM user WHERE useremail = :useremail AND password = :password");
        // binding parameters for mysql insertion
        $result->bindParam(":useremail", $useremail);
        $result->bindParam(":password", $password);
        // mysql inserting a new row with prepared and binded statements
        $result->execute();
        // check if row inserted or not
        if ($result) {
            // check for empty result
            if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {
                $result = $result->fetch();
                // $user = array();
                // $user["useremail"] = $result["useremail"];
                // $user["password"] = $result["password"];
                // // success
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["message"] = "Successfully found the user";
                // user node
                $response["user"] = $result["username"];
                // array_push($response["user"], $user);
                // echoing JSON response
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
         else {
            // failed to insert row
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        print "Sorry, a database error occurred. Please try again later.\n";
        print $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Here is the php code if you guys need to take a look. Again, the server is successfully connected and everything works fine, all the data can be transfered between android and mysql. It's just that weird response delay.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation = "vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/queensflag"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
    android:text="Email"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvUsername"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etUsername" />
<TextView
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvPassword"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Password"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvPassword"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etPassword" />

<Button
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"

    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/blogin"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
<TextView
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/blogin"
    android:id="@+id/tvRegisterLink"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Register"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the xml code if you guys need to take a look. But honestly, its just a normal login xml.

Comment: Mean, at the first time, the progress dialog dismisses.

Comment: add your xml code also

Comment: You stated _but I am pretty sure that the server already received the log in message cuz the second time I tap the login button, it starts activity in response to my first button tap_.

You should check your server log to either be absolutely sure that it happens, or that it does not happen.

Comment: That's what i meant by response shift backward. i tested in multiple ways. if I just use an alert box to indicate a success login without starting a new activity, it shows up right away. Things get off when I start a new activity

Comment: The progress dialog dismisses in the first time I tap the button. That also proves that my android has communicated with php since I only dismiss the processdialog either if it connects or not. But if it does not connect, there will be alert saying "incorrect user information." which I didnt see at all.

Comment: I added the xml code if you guys need to take a look

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, in your volley() method you do the following steps:

1. Declare the StringRequest (with your Response listeners).
2. Send the StringRequest.
3. Check ifReturn.

Due to Volley is asynchronous, you send the StringRequest(2.) and immediately check ifReturn variable(3.), of course it will be false the first time, because there was no time to get the response and call Response listener(1.) to set ifReturn to true.

You should start the activity in onResponse() method from Response.Listener. You don't need to manage ifReturn anymore. Volley only calls onResponse() method when gets response of the request and it was successful. In case of error, onResponseError will be called instead.